# How to add text to an image using package, Images in Julia?

Tags: image, julia

I would like to add text to an image using Images in julia.  
I googled but results are not much helpful in this regard!
Please guide me adding text  at specified co-ordintes to an image using Images in julia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a solution using *only* Images, but you can do something like this with Plots and Images

```
using Plots, Images
img = load("test.png")
plot(img)
annotate!(1.,1.,text("test",20))
```